# Can not access iis hosted site with https on that iis server

Tags: windows, iis, https

I have site that hosted in iis on the Windows Server. It uses https protocol.
It works weel on Internet. But it doesnt work on the server where it is hosted. I mean I cant open it in the browser.
The error in Chrome is ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

I have http sites also on this server. After I added entries to the hosts file they became accessible from the server, but entry for https site didnt help. I mean (127.0.0.1 hostwithhttps.com). Could you tell me what should I change?

Comment: Is you HTTPS site bound to a specific IP address or to all IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Check your local DNS server to be sure a local entry is there.

As your website work from the internet I suspect your host name resolve a public IP even if you are locally next to the server.